# How to group by multiple variables in python ggplot

Tags: python, ggplot2

I want to creat a ggplot in python from the output of cayenne package. My dataset looks like this, I have 10 replicates and 3 types of population: S (Susceptible), I (Infected) and R (Recovered):

```
df

  time rep type  population 
     0   1    S        99.0  
     1   1    S        98.0  
     2   1    S        97.0 
     3   1    S        96.0  
     4   1    S        96.0  
    ..  ...         ...  ..
    95   5    R         NaN  
    96   5    R         NaN  
    97   5    R         NaN  
    98   5    R         NaN  
    99   5    R         NaN
```

I want to get a plot like this:
[Number of Susceptibles, Infecteds and Recovereds over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrZ2t.png)

In R ggplot there is way to use multiple variables in ggplot group argument, like this:

```
group = interaction(rep,type)
```

Is there any equivalent way to do interaction in python ggplot?
Finally I ended up combining two variables in a column and use it as a group:

```
df2 = df
df2['rep'] = df2['rep'].apply(str)
df2 = df2 >> mutate(comb=X.rep+X.type)

print(ggplot(df2)+aes(x='time',y='population',group='comb',colour='type')
      + geom_line() + theme_bw())
```

is there a better way to do it like in R?